# Mock Rails 4 application config custom value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, config, ruby-on-rails-4.2

In Rails::Application, I add a custom configuration using...

```
config.x.cache_config = config_for(:cache)
```

In my tests, I want to see how code using this behaves depending on how the configuration is defined in cache.yml.  To set the various conditions in my rspec tests, I want to do something like...

```
allow(Rails.application.config.x).to recieve(:cache_config).and_return({})
```

But this doesn't work.  It gets an error stating

```
#<Rails::Application::Configuration::Custom ... > does not implement: cache_config
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After much digging and testing in pry, I figured this out.

**Short answer:**

```
allow(Rails.application.config.x).to receive(:method_missing).with(:cache_config).and_return({})
```

Everything in this statement has to be exact except...

- replace **:cache_config** with the name of your custom configuration key
- replace **{}** in the **and_return({})** with the mock value you want to set for the key

**Longer answer:**

If you want to dig into why this is, since it is not at all obvious, check out the code at...

- [Custom class in Rails::Application::Configuration](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master@%7B2017-01-06%7D/railties/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb#L172-L190)
- [Creation of @x for custom configs in Rails::Application::Configuration](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master@%7B2017-01-06%7D/railties/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb#L54)

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone using Mocha, I ended up doing this in a helper

```
Rails.application.config.x.stubs(:my_config).returns(true)
yield
Rails.application.config.x.unstub(:my_config)
```

The `method_missing` trick above didn't work for some reason (guessing to do with differences in the way the stubbing is implemented), failing with an error message about the `Configuration::Custom` class not responding to `method_missing` the first time it was referenced for a different piece of config.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the above answer(s), if you want to stub nested config, then you have to make sure that you're `allow`-ing the second-last piece in the config to `receive(:method_missing)`, as such:

```
allow(Rails.application.config.x.foo.bar).to receive(:method_missing).with(:foobar).and_return(:baz)
```

The above code stubs the `Rails.application.config.x.foo.bar.foobar` config to return `:baz`.